# Get more informative data set produced from Flume+Kafka

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, avro, flume

Kafka, I have configured my Flume Job with Kafka as the source I'm getting Data in my folder which is not informative is there something needs to be changed in my configuration flume
FLume JOb Config

```
#source
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.channels = my-channel
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.batchSize = 10000
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.useFlumeEventFormat = false
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.batchDurationMillis = 5000
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.bootstrap.servers =${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.topics = my-topic
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.group.id = my-topic_grp
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.client.id = my-topic_clnt
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.compressed.topics = my-topic
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.auto.commit.enable = false
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.session.timeout.ms=100000
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.request.timeout.ms=120000
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes=704857
MY_AGENT.sources.my-source.kafka.consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest

#channel
MY_AGENT.channels.my-channel.type = memory
MY_AGENT.channels.my-channel.capacity = 100000000
MY_AGENT.channels.my-channel.transactionCapacity = 100000
MY_AGENT.channels.my-channel.parseAsFlumeEvent = false

#Sink
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.channel = my-channel
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.type = hdfs
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.writeFormat= Text
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.kerberosPrincipal =${user}
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.kerberosKeytab =${keytab}
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://nameservice1/my_hdfs/my_table1/timestamp=%Y%m%d
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.rollCount=0
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.rollSize=0
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.batchSize=100000
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.maxOpenFiles=2000
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.callTimeout=50000

MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer$Builder
MY_AGENT.sinks.my-sink.hdfs.schema.registry.urr=l = ${SCHEMA_URL}
```

O/P of Data

```
﻿0000000: 53 45 51 06 21 6f 72 67 2e 61 70 61 63 68 65 2e SEQ.!org.apache.
0000010: 68 61 64 6f 6f 70 2e 69 6f 2e 4c 6f 6e 67 57 72 hadoop.io.LongWr
0000020: 69 74 61 62 6c 65 22 6f 72 67 2e 61 70 61 63 68 itable"org.apach
0000030: 65 2e 68 61 64 6f 6f 70 2e 69 6f 2e 42 79 74 65 e.hadoop.io.Byte
0000040: 73 57 72 69 74 61 62 6c 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 85 sWritable.......
0000050: a6 6f 46 0c f4 16 33 a6 eb 43 c2 21 5c 1b 4f 00 .oF...3..C.!\.O.
0000060: 00 00 18 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 4d c6 1b 01 1f 00 ..........M.....
0000070: 00 00 0c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 48 44 46 53 21 0d    ...Hello HDFS!.
```

This kind of Output I'm getting I was Expecting json kind of result can there is something needs to be changed in my config flume file